# Add number of days until certain dates as column

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a time-series dataset with hourly dates as index. There is one column indicating whether a particular day is an event (1) or not (0). I would like to add a column counting the days down until an event starts. Whenever there is an event, this column should have the value 0. After the event, it should count down again. Of course, all event dates are assumed to be known.

Here is a minimal example where the column of interest ('y') has been added for better understanding. The example also illustrates the fact that although the dataset ends, one has to think about the next event beyond the time considered in the respective dataframe. In this example, there are 4 days until the next event (which is at 2019-01-08).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
date_range = pd.date_range('01/01/2019 00:00:00','01/04/2019 23:00:00',freq='H')
x = np.zeros(len(date_range))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=x,columns=['x'])
df.set_index(date_range,inplace=True)
df.iloc[48:72] = 1
df['y'] = np.repeat([-2,-1,0,-4],24)
```

I would like to find a way to generate column 'y'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### With `Timedelta`

```
df.assign(
    y=df.index - df.index.to_series().mask(df.x != 1).bfill()
)

                       x                 y
2019-01-01 00:00:00  0.0 -2 days +00:00:00
2019-01-01 01:00:00  0.0 -2 days +01:00:00
2019-01-01 02:00:00  0.0 -2 days +02:00:00
2019-01-01 03:00:00  0.0 -2 days +03:00:00
2019-01-01 04:00:00  0.0 -2 days +04:00:00
...                  ...               ...
2019-01-04 19:00:00  0.0               NaT
2019-01-04 20:00:00  0.0               NaT
2019-01-04 21:00:00  0.0               NaT
2019-01-04 22:00:00  0.0               NaT
2019-01-04 23:00:00  0.0               NaT

[96 rows x 2 columns]
```

If you want an event at the end... just put it there first

```
df.at[pd.Timestamp('2019-01-08'), 'x'] = 1
```

Then the same as above

```
df.assign(
    y=df.index - df.index.to_series().mask(df.x != 1).bfill()
)

                       x                 y
2019-01-01 00:00:00  0.0 -2 days +00:00:00
2019-01-01 01:00:00  0.0 -2 days +01:00:00
2019-01-01 02:00:00  0.0 -2 days +02:00:00
2019-01-01 03:00:00  0.0 -2 days +03:00:00
2019-01-01 04:00:00  0.0 -2 days +04:00:00
...                  ...               ...
2019-01-04 20:00:00  0.0 -4 days +20:00:00
2019-01-04 21:00:00  0.0 -4 days +21:00:00
2019-01-04 22:00:00  0.0 -4 days +22:00:00
2019-01-04 23:00:00  0.0 -4 days +23:00:00
2019-01-08 00:00:00  1.0   0 days 00:00:00

[97 rows x 2 columns]
```

If you had your heart set on integers

```
df.assign(
    y=(
        df.index - 
        df.index.to_series().mask(df.x != 1).bfill()
    ).dt.days
)

                       x  y
2019-01-01 00:00:00  0.0 -2
2019-01-01 01:00:00  0.0 -2
2019-01-01 02:00:00  0.0 -2
2019-01-01 03:00:00  0.0 -2
2019-01-01 04:00:00  0.0 -2
...                  ... ..
2019-01-04 20:00:00  0.0 -4
2019-01-04 21:00:00  0.0 -4
2019-01-04 22:00:00  0.0 -4
2019-01-04 23:00:00  0.0 -4
2019-01-08 00:00:00  1.0  0

[97 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a really cool solution. One short follow-up question: For some reason, adding a new row with a date using `at` doesn't work. It says: "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis". My actual dataset has multiple columns and the index title is timestamp but that's the only difference compared to the minimal example provided. It's probably tough to help if you cannot see the data but maybe you know why this happens. Thanks again!